# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary EF but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I want to connect my ASP.NET MVC web app with the database using Entity Framework Core (v5.17).

But when trying to make it work finally it show me this message :

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[test_deploiement.Models.PublisherModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test_deploiement.Models.PublisherModel]'.

Model class:

```
public class PublisherModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PublisherModel(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public IEnumerable<PublisherModel> Publishers { get; set; }

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult adminpublishermanagement()
    {
        //List<PublisherModel> publisher = new List<PublisherModel>();
        //publisher.Add(new PublisherModel(101, " Lafond"));
        //publisher.Add(new PublisherModel(102, " Casio"));
        //publisher.Add(new PublisherModel(103, "J'aime lire"));
        //publisher.Add(new PublisherModel(104, "Time ofpost"));
        //publisher.Add(new PublisherModel(105, "Le quotidien"));
        Publishers = _db.Publisher_master_tbl;
        return View(Publishers);
    }
}
```

View

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var Publishers in Model)
{
   <tr>
      <td scope="row">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Publishers.Id)</td> 
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Publishers.Name)</td>
  </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

I tried to look if the name of my classes were disfunctional but I'm not sure of it.

Comment: You should look at the error, "requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' which says it requires a `System.Collections.Generic.List` type. As john said, we can use the Tolist method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call .ToList() on the DbSet before passing it to your view:

```
Publishers = _db.Publisher_master_tbl.ToList();
```

Comment: That it, as simple as that, Thank you very much John.